# Why does xlsx files get corrupted when I send them to a Node.js API?

Tags: node.js

Let's say I have the following `api.js` developed with Node.js:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const file = '/home/raylight/output.xlsx'
const app = express();
const port = 3333;

app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/uploadFile', (req, res) => {
    const myFile = Buffer.from(req.body.buffer.data)
    fs.writeFileSync(file, myFile, { encoding: 'binary' })
    res.send('Request successful');
});

app.listen(port);
console.log(`Listening on port ${port}!`)
```

I also have the following `request.js` code that saves a `xlsx` file inside a buffer and sends it to my previous API using an `axios` POST:

```js
const fs = require("fs")
const axios = require("axios")

const inputFile = "/home/raylight/input.xlsx"

async function requests() {
    try {
        const buffer = fs.readFileSync(inputFile, { encoding: "binary" })
        const object = {
                method: 'post',
                url: "http://127.1.1.1:3333/uploadFile",
                data: { "filename": "output.xlsx", buffer: Buffer.from(buffer)},
            }
        const postResponse = await axios(object)
        console.log(postResponse)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
requests()
```

This code is corrupting the `xlsx` file while sending it. I've tried tweaking this code in different ways, like taking out the `Buffer.from()` function, changing `binary` to `utf8`, and putting `'Content-Type' : 'application/octet-stream'` as the headers of my request... But none of them work and I always end up with a broken `xlsx` file...

[image]

When I try to do the same with csv files and I use `utf8` as encoding it works fine. What am I missing? What do I have to do in order to send `xlsx` files without corrupting them with a Node.js API?

Comment: What is the content of the resulting file you tried to open ? It is possible that the wrong value is being written in the file instead of the data you expect.

Comment: @Seblor The content is binary... Both LibreOffice and text editors show a bunch of weird characters while opening the file. About the parameters, I've used a `console.log` to be sure that I'm getting the buffered data properly. I'm sure I'm getting the right parameter... But for some reason, the data seems to be modified during the request (even though if I `console.log` their length they match exactly the same 25966 on the client and on the server)

Comment: What does `file` have to say about the content?

Comment: @tadman I've modified the question and I've changed `file` to `filename` on my second code... Even though the first API code `file` is hardcoded, the final version needs to receive both the file content and its name on the request... That's why there's an object with the buffer content and a string with a name.

Comment: I mean the `file` command which can usually suss out what kind of data format you have. Maybe it's an XLS file. Maybe it's a ZIP or GZip data stream.

Comment: It prints `output.xlsx: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract`... I've tried renaming the file to `output.zip` and then extracting it. But I received an error... Using `unzip output.zip` I got `error [output.zip]:  missing 4464503 bytes in zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
error [output.zip]:  start of central directory not found;
  zipfile corrupt.`...

Comment: Express suggests using the `multer` middleware for files / multipart : https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html

Answer (score 0):

try including the same encoding when converting to buffer:

```
data: { "filename": "output.xlsx", buffer: Buffer.from(buffer, 'binary')},
```